# Is there an idiom that means "the more powerful you are the more enemies you have" or something similar?

Tags: idioms

It's difficult to find an idiom on Google for a certain idea, but I honestly couldn't find anything even after looking for idioms and a keyword like "power".

Comment: Here:https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/enemies?page=1 you can find lots of quotes including the word "enemies".

Comment: Is there such a thing in your native language?

Answer (score -1):

There's a saying with a similar meaning:

> The harder they come, the harder they fall.

This means that the more force you use against someone or something, the more you'll suffer in the end. Or another interpretation might be that it's dangerous to wield a lot of power because it can be turned against you.